# Angular - How to use animations for moving a html object?

Tags: css, angular

I use @angular/animations module for moving html objects.
I would like to move object on button click.

For example:
* object has attrs top: 800px, left: 800px
* sb click 'W' button
* object has attrs top: 700px, left: 800px
* sb click 'W' button
* object has attrs top: 600px, left: 800px

I tried this:

```
animations: [
    trigger('up', [
      state('1', style({
        transform: 'translateY(-100px)',
      })),

      transition('* <=> 1', animate('200ms'))
    ])
  ]
```

but everytime when I release the 'W' key, object returns to (800, 800) position.

What can I do?

Comment: You have it explicitly set to to go back and forth `* <=> 1`, it's like the CSS equivalent of forgetting to add `animation-direction: forwards`. So you'll need to specify the start state for `=>` and the end state for `<=` which you can find a detailed of explanation [here](https://angular.io/guide/transition-and-triggers)

Answer (score 0):

It only applies CSS styles to perform animation, and those styles are removed after trigger is gone. What you have to do is to update actual element position after animation is done so it will be like

1. Item is at post 800,800
2. Animate item to 700,800 (translateX(-100px))
3. On animation complete - set item position to 700,800

Voila, efect is persistent.